# Custom post types não funciona corretamente

Tags: php, wordpress

Eu criei dois "Custom Post Type", com os seguintes nomes "Filmes" e o outro "Series", ambos utilizam as mesmas "Register Taxonomy".

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

No entanto quando eu faço uma busca como por exemplo:

Quando filtro somente o gênero "Ação", o site me retorna outras postagens que não tem o mesmo gênero, o sistema lista todos os filmes e series e ignora o termo filtrado.

Aqui esta a função do "Custom Post Type" Filmes (O Séries e idêntico, só muda os parâmetros da função, logico kkk)

```
add_action( 'init', 'post_type_movies' );

function post_type_movies() {

  $labels = array(
    'name'                => __( 'Filme', mundothemes ),
    'singular_name'       => __( 'Filmes', mundothemes ),
    'add_new'             => __( 'Adicionar Novo', mundothemes ),
    'add_new_item'        => __( 'Adicionar Novo Filme', mundothemes ),
    'edit_item'           => __( 'Editar Filme', mundothemes ),
    'new_item'            => __( 'Novo Filme', mundothemes ),
    'all_items'           => __( 'Todos os Filmes', mundothemes ),
    'view_item'           => __( 'Ver Filme', mundothemes ),
    'search_items'        => __( 'Pesquisar Filme', mundothemes ),
    'not_found'           => __( 'Nenhum filme encontrado', mundothemes ),
    'not_found_in_trash'  => __( 'Nenhum filme na lixeira', mundothemes ),
    'menu_name'           => __( 'Filmes', mundothemes ),
  );

  $supports = array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'comments');

  $slug = get_theme_mod( 'movies_permalink' );
  $slug = ( empty( $slug ) ) ? 'filmes' : $slug;

  $args = array(
    'labels'              => $labels,
    'public'              => true,
    'publicly_queryable'  => true,
    'show_ui'             => true,
    'show_in_menu'        => true,
    'query_var'           => true,
    'rewrite'             => array( 'slug' => $slug ),
    'capability_type'     => 'post',
    'has_archive'         => true,
    'hierarchical'        => false,
    'menu_position'       => 4,
    'supports'            => $supports,
    'menu_icon'           => 'dashicons-editor-video',
  );

  register_post_type( 'filmes', $args );

}
```

Aqui esta a função do "Register Taxonomy" Gênero (Essa função eu utilizo em ambos os Custom Post Type)

```
add_action( 'init', 'custom_taxonomy_genre', 0 );

function custom_taxonomy_genre() {
    register_taxonomy(
        'genero', // COLOCAR EM PT-BR
        array('series','filmes'), // DEFINE O TIPO DE POST - CUSTOM POST TYPE
        array( 'hierarchical' => true, 'label' => 'Gênero', 'query_var' => true, 'rewrite' => true )
    );   
}
```

Não sei o motivo desse erro, será que falta adicionar algo mais a função ou o motivo e outro?

Comment: Poderia fornecer mais detalhes? Como, por exemplo, como é feita a chamada aos métodos. Pois a pergunta parece não cumprir os requisitos de [exemplo Mínimo, Completo e Verificável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Digamos que eu click sobre um link com o termo "ação",então sou redirecionado para: "http://localhost/genero/acao/" porem em vez de o sistema filtrar as postagens que tem o mesmo termo, que seria "ação", a pagina me retorna todos as postagem do site, ignorando o termo de busca.

Comment: em tese eu já resolvi o meu problema, no entanto se alguém tiver uma solução melhor que essa, por favor compartilhe. Eu resolvi da seguinte maneira, eu criei um arquivo chamado "taxonomy-genero.php", copiei o mesmo código da index, porem removi o array que filtrava os dois custom post type, deixando apenas "<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>", o lado ruim e que eu atualmente tenho 10 taxonomy, ou seja, vou ter que criar 10 paginas com o nome "taxonomy-{taxonomy}.php".

Comment: novamente resolvi meu problema kkkk, apenas removi o "genero" do nome deixando o arquivo assim "taxonomy.php" e resolveu, tem hora que eu acho q sou um gênio ou muito burro mesmo rs.

Comment: Hahahaha eu ia sugerir [Herança de Objetos](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.oop5.inheritance.php)

Comment: foi tão simples, e eu fiquei a manhã toda quebrando cabeça com isso.